# Count all +1's in the file python

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have the following data:

```
  1 3 4 2 6 7 8 8 93 23 45 2 0 0 0 1
  0 3 4 2 6 7 8 8 90 23 45 2 0 0 0 1
  0 3 4 2 6 7 8 6 93 23 45 2 0 0 0 1
  -1 3 4 2 6 7 8 8 21 23 45 2 0 0 0 1
  -1 3 4 2 6 7 8 8 0 23 45 2 0 0 0 1
```

The above data is in a file. I want to count the number of 1's,0's,-1's but only in 1st column. I am taking the file in standard input but the only way I could think of is to do like this:

```
  cnt = 0
  cnt1 = 0
  cnt2 = 0
  for line in sys.stdin:
      (t1, <having 15 different variables as that many columns are in files>) = re.split("\s+", line.strip())
      if re.match("+1", t1):
         cnt = cnt + 1
      if re.match("-1", t1):
         cnt1 = cnt1 + 1
      if re.match("0", t1):
         cnt2 = cnt2 + 1
```

How can I make it better especially the 15 different variables part as thats the only place where I will be using those variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
with open('abc.txt') as f:
    c = Counter(int(line.split(None, 1)[0]) for line in f)
    print c
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({0: 2, -1: 2, 1: 1})
```

Here `str.split(None, 1)` splits the line just once:

```
>>> s = "1 3 4 2 6 7 8 8 93 23 45 2 0 0 0 1"                                                
>>> s.split(None, 1)
['1', '3 4 2 6 7 8 8 93 23 45 2 0 0 0 1']
```

---

[Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) makes it even easy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from collections import Counter                                                         
>>> Counter(np.loadtxt('abc.txt', usecols=(0,), dtype=np.int))                                     
Counter({0: 2, -1: 2, 1: 1})
```

Comment: You should highlight the usage of `line.split(None, 1)`, i.e., the split limit. (and why do you use "None" as the delimiter?)

Comment: Nested (in-)comprehensions (alright, alright, I know - generator expressions), aarrghh!

Comment: `None` is special-cased to split on sequences of whitespace.  Perlishly, if you ask me ...

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the first column, then only split the first column.  And use a dictionary to store the counts for each value.

```
count = dict()
for line in sys.stdin:
    (t1, rest) = line.split(' ', 1)
    try:
        count[t1] += 1
    except KeyError:
        count[t1] = 1
for item in count:
    print '%s occurs %i times' % (item, count[item])
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using tuple unpacking, where you need a number of variables exactly equal to the number of parts returned by split(), you can just use the first element of those parts:

```
parts = re.split("\s+", line.strip())
t1 = parts[0]
```

or equivalently, simply

```
t1 = re.split("\s+", line.strip())[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections

def countFirstColum(fileName):
    res = collections.defaultdict(int)
    with open(fileName) as f:
    for line in f:
        key = line.split(" ")[0]
        res[key] += 1;
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from a script of mine with an infile, I checked and it works with standard input as infile:

```
dictionary = {}

for line in someInfile:
    line = line.strip('\n') # if infile but you should
    f = line.split() #  do your standard input thing
    dictionary[f[0]]=0

for line in someInfile:
    line = line.strip('\n') # if infile but you should
    f = line.split() #  do your standard input thing
    dictionary[f[0]]+=1

print dictionary
```

Comment: This will produce zero-based counts, on the second field in the file.  Maybe use 1 instead of 0 in the `if`?  And `f[0]` instead of `f[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = []
for line in f:
    column = line.strip().split(" ")
    rows.append(column)
```

then you get a 2-dimensional array.

1st column:

```
for row in rows:
    print row[0]
```

output:

```
1
0
0
-1
-1
```